# regex to match until word but not include that keyword

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this regex, the ouput is a bit strange, when i echo the body of the email is dont see line breaks but

When i run this:

```
Message:(.*?)
```

Instead of it returning everything after Message it returns the whole body of the email as if its ignoring line breaks

So i tried this and it worked

```
Message:(.*?)Issue
```

That captures everything from the first keyword to the last however it includes the keyword also for Issue which i dont want, how to include everything except Issue not including?

Also when i return the string i get
Message: this is a test\r

Is there a better way other than running a str_replace to remove those?
Im a bit of a regex virgin :)

Comment: can you post (and format) the relevant code?

Comment: Can you re-phrase this in more of an "example input vs expected output" manner?

Comment: "echo and don't see linebreaks"? If you're echoing into a web browser, remember that browsers do NOT honor linebreak chars. You'd need to run the email through `nl2br()` to change all the `\r` and `\n` into `<br>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [positive forward lookahead](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php):

```
preg_match('/Message:(.*?)(?=Issue)/', 'Message: blah blah Issue', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => Message: blah blah
    [1] =>  blah blah
)
```